# Gridview paging style in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, styling

i have a gridview, and need a specific pagination style, for the Paging, here's what the output i need, can anyone tell me how can i achieve this:
[image: Custom pagination design in gridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **<kbd>PagerPosition Enumeration - TopAndBottom</kbd>**

This property will display the pager at both **<kbd>Top and Bottom</kbd>**

### <kbd>MARK UP</kbd>

```
<PagerTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First">First</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="pmore" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev">Pre</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p0" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p1" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p2" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="CurrentPage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p4" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p5" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="p6" runat="server" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next">Next</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="nmore" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last">Last</asp:LinkButton>
</PagerTemplate>
```

---

### <kbd>Code Behind</kbd>

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.BottomPagerRow;
    Label lb1 = (Label)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPage");
    lb1.Text = Convert.ToString(GridView1.PageIndex+1);
    int[] page = new int[7];
    page[0] = GridView1.PageIndex - 2;
    page[1] = GridView1.PageIndex - 1;
    page[2] = GridView1.PageIndex;
    page[3] = GridView1.PageIndex + 1;
    page[4] = GridView1.PageIndex + 2;
    page[5] = GridView1.PageIndex + 3;
    page[6] = GridView1.PageIndex + 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (i != 3)
        {
            if (page[i] < 1 || page[i] > GridView1.PageCount )
            {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p" + Convert.ToString(i));
                lb.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p" + Convert.ToString(i));
                lb.Text = Convert.ToString(page[i]);

                lb.CommandName = "PageNo";
                lb.CommandArgument = lb.Text;

            } 
        }
    }
    if (GridView1.PageIndex == 0)
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton1");
        lb.Visible = false;
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton2");
        lb.Visible = false;

    }
    if (GridView1.PageIndex == GridView1.PageCount - 1)
    {
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton3");
        lb.Visible = false;
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton4");
        lb.Visible = false;

    }
    if (GridView1.PageIndex > GridView1.PageCount - 5)
    {
        Label lbmore = (Label)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("nmore");
        lbmore.Visible = false;
    }
    if (GridView1.PageIndex < 4)
    {
        Label lbmore = (Label)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("pmore");
        lbmore.Visible = false;
    }

}

void lb_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
}

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p0");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p1");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p2");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p4");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p5");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
        lb = (LinkButton)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("p6");
        lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command);
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1235573.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Nilish, great answer, this is what i was looking for, but i am unable to display paging with this in top, even after setting PagerSetting Position="TopAndBottom"

Comment: Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.position.aspx

Comment: that does not help me, as they are just referring bottom position, i want topandbottom both.

Comment: Just replace the Bottom with TopAndBottom

Comment: Seems the problem was, in the above code, the implementation is for the BottomPagerRow, so need to implement TopPagerRow explicitly, anyways its working now.. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

Inside the GridView Properties there one that is called PaggerSettings.
Inside this one you have the FirstPageImageUrl, LastPageImageUrl and so on.
In this fields is whrere you should put an image with those corners and backgound that you want.